# Dialogflow with Botium Testing : how to generate report file

Tags: automated-tests, command-line-interface, dialogflow-es

My botium is running and can already test my dialogflow bot, but it seems i have problem in getting the report to output files like CSV or mochawesome html. Either way the result was shown only in the terminal command line

I write in CLI like this :

> botium-cli run csv

OR

> botium-cli run mochawesome

I am using dialogflow for LINE BOT and following this [tutorial](https://chatbotsmagazine.com/3-steps-setup-automated-testing-for-google-assistant-and-dialogflow-de42937e57c6). But it does not say much about generating the test output.

How do I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Botium CLI provides help on the available reporters and options by adding the *--help* flag (as usual):

```
botium-cli run --help
```

will show command line help of the available output formats and other options.

Comment: I did, that's why I know I should run botium-cli run mochawesome

Comment: can you add the --verbose switch and post the output here